# Why does the landing trajectory of a blunt body take an S shape in the lower atmosphere?

Tags: reentry, landing, trajectory, entry-descent-landing

I coded some Matlab plots of altitude vs time for the re-entry of a point mass (so no aerothermo analysis included). In all the trajectories, there is an S shape closer to the ground. Why? Please could I know specifically in reference to blunt bodies?

Comment: This will be easier to answer with an example plot and link to the matlab code being run.

Comment: It should be noted that aerothermal analysis can be done on point masses (just not distributed aerothermal analysis).

Comment: Possibly-relevant: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/14720/22816